# re.findall returns just first match

Tags: python, regex

I had a look on similar open questions, but I didnt found yet the solution I'm looking for.

I have a list of words (or small sentences) like that:

```
list_words = ["hi", "hi frank"] # this list is huge! this is just an example!
```

I have a text like this:

```
string_text = "hi jane. hi frank!"
```

I want know how many time the words in list_words are present inside string_text

My solution is this:

```
re.findall("|".join(list_words), string_text)
['hi', 'hi']
```

Look that if I change the order of words

```
list_words2 = ["hi frank", "hi"]
```

my solution returns

```
re.findall("|".join(list_words2), string_text)
['hi', 'hi frank']
```

Quit bad I guess.

The solution I would like to have is this:

```
["hi", "hi", "hi frank"]
```

or at least

```
["hi", "hi frank"]
```

but I like to have the same solution with any permutations of list_words!!

Note that I could easy solve this problem by looping over words in list_words and apply a findall at each step. But it will be to expensive I guess.

Can you help me?

Comment: "Note that I could easy solve this problem by looping over words in list_words and apply a findall at each step." Not just the easy way - the only way. You're looking for a count of matches to set of possibly overlapping regexes - the only way of getting a count for each regex pattern while being sure the match didn't get clobbered by another pattern `|`-ed with it is to do one `findall` call per pattern.

Comment: With the given restrictions "any permutations of list_words" and "no loop over list_words" this can't be solved. Without first restriction at least the second best solution `["hi", "hi frank"]` is possible.